# To get values from hidden field

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a dynamic hidden field Now i like to get all the hidden field values.But i get only one value.Pls help me to solve the issue.
Js:

```
var hid = document.getElementById("<%= hidRegExp.ClientID %>").value;
        alert(hid);
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp"  runat="server" value="1" >
</asp:HiddenField >
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp"  runat="server" value="2">
</asp:HiddenField >
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp"  runat="server" value="3">
</asp:HiddenField >
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp"  runat="server" value="4" >
</asp:HiddenField >
```

Comment: if all the fields will have same id or class, you will get only one value. So you need to have elements with different id or class and access them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Same id `hidRegExp` can not used for multiple tags, use unique `id` and get the value from particular element by using particular id. Like

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp"  runat="server" value="1" > </asp:HiddenField >
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp2"  runat="server" value="2"> </asp:HiddenField >

//from first element
var hid = document.getElementById("<%= hidRegExp.ClientID %>").value; 

//from second element    
var hid2 = document.getElementById("<%= hidRegExp2.ClientID %>").value;
```

Comment: Is there any way to split the value and store in a variable

Comment: you meant to say this kind of value  `value="1"` should be store into variable ?

Comment: It is a 1 hidden field and it is dynamic .i like to split all the values by delimiter and store in a variable

Comment: I can't get you, can you please describe more about this?